# Pagination: how to set the number of pages?

Tags: django, django-pagination

I have a view for showing the list of news items:

```
def index(request, page_number=1):
    news_list = get_list_or_404(NewsItem.objects.order_by('-pub_date'))
    news_paginator = Paginator(news_list, 10)
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', {'news_list': news_paginator.page(page_number))
```

As you can see, ten news items are displayed on every page.

The template:

```
<div class="paginator">
  <ul>
    <!-- Left arrow -->
      {% if news_list.has_previous %}
        <li class="arrow"><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' news_list.previous_page_number %}"><b>&larr;</b></a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="arrow unavailable"><b>&larr;</b></li>
      {% endif %}

    <!-- Page numbers -->
      {% for page in news_list.paginator.page_range %}
         {% if page == news_list.number  %}
           <li class="current"><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' page %}">{{ page }}</a></li>
         {% else %}
           <li><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' page %}">{{ page }}</a></li>
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

     <!-- Right arrow -->
       {% if news_list.has_next %}
         <li class="arrow"><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' news_list.next_page_number %}"><b>&rarr;</b></a></li>
       {% else %}
         <li class="arrow unavailable"><b>&rarr;</b></li>
       {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

← 1   **2**   3   4   5   6    7    8 →

Let's imagine there are 217 news items, and I wouldn't like to have 21 page numbers at the bottom of the list. Instead, I'd prefer to set the limit: only 5 page numbers. But this limit has to be *stable*, there always should be 5 page numbers regardless the current position in the list of the pages:

← 1   **2**   3   4   5    →

← 11   12   **13**   14   15 → (*in the middle of the list*)

←  17   18   19   20   **21** → (*the last page is shown*)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506609/how-organize-pagination-with-a-large-number-of-pages-in-django-project/63507365#63507365

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in your views.py:

```
class Counter:
    count = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1
        return ''
```

Then add it to:

```
context = {'news_list': news_paginator.page(page_number),'Counter':Counter}
return render(request, 'news/index.html', context)
```

Then on your html page:

```
  {% for page in news_list.paginator.page_range %}
     {% if page == news_list.number  %}  

     {% if Counter.count < 6 %}
     {{ Counter.increment }} 
       <li class="current"><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' page %}">{{ page }}</a></li>
     {% endif %}

     {% else %}
       <li><a class="no_underline" href="{% url 'news:index' page %}">{{ page }}</a></li>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't seem to be working. I did exactly what you had suggested, but the list isn't split and the current page is hidden.